# Repopulate listview by correct id?

Tags: android, listview, populate

(Firstly, I am sorry my bad English, please fix it)

Hi, I can populate the listview from the database and ıf I click to any listview item, it go to "Detail.class" by related "id".

The problem is when I re-populate with lesson (lesson= " WHERE deck='" + lesson + "'";), listview correctly populate but listview index/id ? aren't change and when I click listview item, "Detail.class" is opening but by wrong id.

----- database helper class ---

```
    if (lesson.equals("")) {
        lesson= "";

    } else {
        lesson= " WHERE deck='" + MainActivity.lesson + "'";

    }


    String selectQuery = "select word, id,word,typ from TAB" + lesson + " group by id";
```

---- MainActivity class ----

```
private void loadListview() {
    Database db = new Database(getApplicationContext());
    List<String> labels = db.makeList();

    dataAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.listview_spc, labels);

    Listview1 = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.liAll);
    Listview1.setAdapter(dataAdapter);

}


    Listview1.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2,
                                long arg3) {

                Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Detail.class); 
                intent.putExtra("id", (int) word_ids[arg2]); // I think the problem is here.
                startActivity(intent);
                  }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

replace clicklistner code to below ,

```
listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                        Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), Detail.class);
                        intent.putExtra("Id",labels.get(position).getId());
                        startActivity(intent);
                    }
                });
```

Comment: having any issues ?@Tunc

Comment: Thanks but yes. getId() is gives "Cannot resolve method" error. And why do you change "id" to "Id".

Comment: ok. you can do as **labels.get(position);** to get position of element you clicked

Comment: Sorry doesnt work. maybe the problem is somewhere else. I'll think about it.

Comment: actually you want to get position of clicked item than (int position) in function will give you position and based on that you can get data from your list, you can tell me if you are stuck somewhere